# Removing a comment added during review should invalidate the "Other action"

Tags: bug, review-queues, comments

In review (in my case, in *First questions*), you can select the "Other action" without doing anything else.

1. **Add a comment**. Everything works.
2. **Remove your comment**. I tried without any other action between, and it's fine. No time to wait.
3. Now you can **click on "Other action"** without any (net) action made.

It's a bug for me, because we can do review, but without giving real feedback or managing them. All will be considered as "Reviewed" but they are not, such as there isn't any comment.

PS: Always working in 2024.

Comment: I'm not sure we need to be that sophisticated in tracking what changed. If a reviewer goes through that much trouble to do essentially nothing, they're wasting a lot of energy for little to no gain.

Comment: @HereticMonkey It's possible to do an auto reviewer by putting a comment then remove it. It will just say it's an audit when it's one

Comment: I don't think this is the most direct logic to solve the problem. why not: "'other' can only be selected when some number of 'other' actions have 'survived' by the time of review submission"?

Comment: @starball the logic is to don't be able to say you made "Other action" if you cancelled what you did. Here it's the comment, but maybe it can work by flagging then cancelling flag idk, if you have no impact/no change, it should be a skip and not a real action